Filter data and stacked bar plot (R)
I would like to filter data for value then make  a stacked bar plot. The data from two variables column (Species name, AMR Class).
I tried using the code below but did not work out. Please help...
Thank you very much for any help.
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

df <-V_microbigge
head(df)
V_microbigge %>%
filter('AMR Class' == "PHENICOL" | 
'AMR Class' == "TETRACYCLINE" |
'AMR Class' == "BETA-LACTAM" |
'AMR Class' == "FOSFOMYCIN" |
'AMR Class' == "MERCURY" |
'AMR Class' == "COLISTIN" |
'AMR Class' == "AMINOGLYCOSIDE" |
'AMR Class' == "RIFAMYCIN" |
'AMR Class' == "QUATERNARY AMMONIUM" |
'AMR Class' == "BLEOMYCIN" |
'AMR Class' == "TRIMETHOPRIM" |
'AMR Class' == "AMINOGLYCOSIDE" |
'AMR Class' == "QUINOLONE" |
'AMR Class' == "SULFONAMIDE"|
'AMR Class' == "ARSENIC") %>%

ggplot(aes('Species name', fill('AMR Class'))+
geom_bar(position = fill), alpha = 0.5)+
theme_bw()+
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
labs(title = "AMR Classes",
x = "Species name",
y = "Number")


Welcome to SO! Try with ...%>% filter(\AMR Class` %in% c("PHENICOL", "TETRACYCLINE", ....)) %>% ggplot(aes(`Species name`, fill = `AMR Class`)), i.e. put the column names containing spaces inside backticks instead of quotes. I also used %in%to simplify the filter condition. Also, it should begeom_bar(position = "fill"). For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your input data best shared using dput()` or using some fake data.

Thanks stefan
Data
Specie (a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,c,c,c)
AMR (v,v,w,x,z,w,x,x,y,v,y,z)
I tried
%>%
filter(AMR %in% c("v", "w", "x", "y", "z")) %>%
ggplot(aes(Specie, fill = AMR))
geom_bar(position = "fill")
With this get only outer barline... I would like to have a stacked barplot, where x the Specie and y the stacked AMR values for each categories. Can you please advise

We can't help you any further without any data. To share a snippet of your data run e.g. V_microbigge %>% filter(.....) %>% dput() and add the output using copy & paste to your question.


V_microbigge_test %>%


filter(AMR %in% c("v", "w", "x", "y", "z")) %>%
dput()
structure(list(Specie = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b",
"b", "b", "c", "c", "c"), AMR = c("v", "v", "w", "x", "z", "w",
"x", "x", "y", "v", "y", "z")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -12L))

i try with test data

Not sure what's the issue. When I run ggplot(df, aes(Specie, fill = AMR)) + geom_bar(position = "fill") (where df is the data you provided via dput) I get a stacked bar chart: https://i.sstatic.net/G0QXG.png

Great, got the barplot, thanks stefan. How can i have the count in y axis to be the exact count?

Drop position="fill" from geom_bar. Then you will get a stacked barchart of  the counts.
